# Call groovy function in Jenkinsfile, where jenkins and groovy files are in different folders

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline and try to call a `printCounter` function (on vars folder) in the `DQJenkinsfile` (on `Jenkinsfile` folder). The DQJenkinsfile and printCounter file (groovy code) are in different folders. Here is the git repo for that [link](https://github.com/leotrn9x/testPipiline)

In the Jenkins script I created the counter object and make that object call the `printCounter` function. However, I got error in the jenkins that it is unable to resolve class counter. Could anyone recommend me the solution?

Comment: You don't exactly have a class called `counter` in your repo. Just a method `counter.printCounter`?

Comment: Yes I don’t have the class but can I just call the function without create object like that? Sorry I’m from OOP programming so I don’t know the concept here.

Comment: For starters, move the function to the end of your jenkinsfile (and call it just `printCounter`, not `counter.printCounter`), then instead of initializing an object, simply reference the function you created `printCounter()`,

Comment: Jenkins turns each Groovy script in the vars folder into a singleton class with an instance named like the script. So the calling syntax `counter.printCounter` in the Jenkinsfile is correct. But in the "counter.groovy" file the function should just be named `def printCounter()`. Imagine the Groovy script being wrapped in a class (which is what happens), so you just write the method names, as you would in a class.

Comment: Also, in the Jenkinsfile remove the line `def counter = new counter()`. As I wrote, scripts in `vars` folder are automatically instanciated by Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just backed from the vacation and will try these solutions soon!

Answer (score 0):

i assume you dont use this as jenkins shared library so you need to change code

```
script {
  def counter = load 'vars/counter.groovy'
  counter.printCounter()
}
```

and conter.groovy

```
def printCounter(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        println("count: $i")
    }
}

return this;
```

`def counter.printCounter(){` you can not use dot in function name

see [load](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) and [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)